# Divide 64-bit integers as though the dividend is shifted left 64 bits, without having 128-bit types

Tags: c, integer-division, 128-bit, int128

Apologies for the confusing title. I'm not sure how to better describe what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm essentially trying to do the reverse of 
[getting the high half of a 64-bit multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28868367/getting-the-high-part-of-64-bit-integer-multiplication) in C for platforms where

```
int64_t divHi64(int64_t dividend, int64_t divisor) {
    return ((__int128)dividend << 64) / (__int128)divisor;
}
```

isn't possible due to lacking support for `__int128`.

Comment: What do you want to return when the quotient cannot be represented by a `int64_t`?

Comment: The other question was about two 64-bit operands being multiplied, which can need 128 bits to hold the product. That never happens with integer division.

Comment: @IanAbbott For this scenario it can simply truncate the result if it would exceed 64 bits.

Comment: are you using MSVC? [128-bit division intrinsic in Visual C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8453146/995714), [Intrinsics for 128 multiplication and division](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32540740/995714). Related: [64 bit / 64 bit remainder finding algorithm on a 32 bit processor?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44128656/995714), [Unsigned 128-bit division on 64-bit machine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1870158/995714)

Comment: You should consider employing an arbitrary-precision arithmetic package, such as [GMP](https://gmplib.org/).  That will give you a clean and clear way of doing the job at the cost of adding a program dependency.  If you want to implement it yourself, then a variety of algorithms are known; Wikipedia presents [some of the more popular ones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm).

Comment: There was an only-link-answer pointing at https://www.hackersdelight.org/hdcodetxt/divmnu64.c.txt which might be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done without a multi-word division

Suppose we want to do ⌊2<sup>64</sup> × <sup>x</sup>⁄<sub>y</sub>⌋ then we can transform the expression like this

[image: Unicode math: ⌊(2^64 x)/y⌋=⌊(⌊2^64/y⌋+{2^64/y})x⌋=⌊2^64/y⌋x+⌊{2^64/y}x┤]

The first term is trivially done as `((-y)/y + 1)*x` as per this question [How to compute 2⁶⁴/n in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55565537/995714)

The second term is equivalent to (2<sup>64</sup> % y)/y*x and is a little bit trickier. I've tried various ways but all need 128-bit multiplication and 128/64 division if using only integer operations. That can be done using the algorithms to calculate `MulDiv64(a, b, c) = a*b/c` in the below questions

- [Most accurate way to do a combined multiply-and-divide operation in 64-bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8733178/995714)
- [How to multiply a 64 bit integer by a fraction in C++ while minimizing error?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25182577/995714)
- [(a * b) / c MulDiv and dealing with overflow from intermediate multiplication](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54232987/995714)
- [How can I multiply and divide 64-bit ints accurately?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18022544/995714)

However they may be slow, and if you have those functions you calculate the whole expression more easily like `MulDiv64(x, UINT64_MAX, y) + x/y + something` without messing up with the above transformation

Using `long double` seems to be the easiest way if it has 64 bits of precision or more. So now it can be done by (2<sup>64</sup> % y)/(long double)y*x

```
uint64_t divHi64(uint64_t x, uint64_t y) {
    uint64_t mod_y = UINT64_MAX % y + 1;
    uint64_t result = ((-y)/y + 1)*x;
    if (mod_y != y)
        result += (uint64_t)((mod_y/(long double)y)*x);
    return result;
}
```

The overflow check was omitted for simplification. A slight modification will be needed if you need signed division

---

If you're targeting **64-bit Windows** but you're using MSVC which doesn't have `__int128` then [now it has a 128-bit/64-bit divide intrinsic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56033459/995714) which simplifies the job significantly without a 128-bit integer type. You still need to handle overflow though because the [`div` instruction](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/div) will throw an exception on that case

```
uint64_t divHi64(uint64_t x, uint64_t y) {
    uint64_t high, remainder;
    uint64_t low = _umul128(UINT64_MAX, y, &high);
    if (x <= high /* && 0 <= low */)
        return _udiv128(x, 0, y, &remainder);
    // overflow case
    errno = EOVERFLOW;
    return 0;
}
```

The overflow checking above is can be simplified to checking whether x < y, because if x >= y then the result will overflow

---

See also

- [Efficient Multiply/Divide of two 128-bit Integers on x86 (no 64-bit)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8776073/995714)
- [Efficient computation of 2**64 / divisor via fast floating-point reciprocal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36853827/995714)

---

Exhaustive tests on 16/16 bit division shows that my solution works correctly for all cases. However you do need `double` even though `float` has more than 16 bits of precision, otherwise occasionally a less-than-one result will be returned. It may be fixed by adding an *epsilon* value before truncating: `(uint64_t)((mod_y/(long double)y)*x + epsilon)`. That means you'll need `__float128` (or the [`-m128bit-long-double` option](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html)) in gcc for precise 64/64-bit output if you don't correct the result with *epsilon*. However [that type is available on 32-bit targets](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Floating-Types.html), unlike `__int128` which is supported only on 64-bit targets, so life will be a bit easier. Of course you can use the function as-is if just a very close result is needed

Below is the code I've used for verifying

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <climits>
#include <mutex>

std::mutex print_mutex;

#define MAX_THREAD 8
#define NUM_BITS   27
#define CHUNK_SIZE (1ULL << NUM_BITS)

// typedef uint32_t T;
// typedef uint64_t T2;
// typedef double D;
typedef uint64_t T;
typedef unsigned __int128 T2;   // the type twice as wide as T
typedef long double D;
// typedef __float128 D;
const D epsilon = 1e-14;
T divHi(T x, T y) {
    T mod_y = std::numeric_limits<T>::max() % y + 1;
    T result = ((-y)/y + 1)*x;
    if (mod_y != y)
        result += (T)((mod_y/(D)y)*x + epsilon);
    return result;
}

void testdiv(T midpoint)
{
    T begin = midpoint - CHUNK_SIZE/2;
    T end   = midpoint + CHUNK_SIZE/2;
    for (T i = begin; i != end; i++)
    {
        T x = i & ((1 << NUM_BITS/2) - 1);
        T y = CHUNK_SIZE/2 - (i >> NUM_BITS/2);
        // if (y == 0)
            // continue;
        auto q1 = divHi(x, y);
        T2 q2 = ((T2)x << sizeof(T)*CHAR_BIT)/y;
        if (q2 != (T)q2)
        {
            // std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(print_mutex);
            // std::cout << "Overflowed: " << x << '&' << y << '\n';
            continue;
        }
        else if (q1 != q2)
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(print_mutex);
            std::cout << x << '/' << y << ": " << q1 << " != " << (T)q2 << '\n';
        }
    }
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(print_mutex);
        std::cout << "Done testing [" << begin << ", " << end << "]\n";
}


uint16_t divHi16(uint32_t x, uint32_t y) {
    uint32_t mod_y = std::numeric_limits<uint16_t>::max() % y + 1;
    int result = ((((1U << 16) - y)/y) + 1)*x;
    if (mod_y != y)
        result += (mod_y/(double)y)*x;
    return result;
}

void testdiv16(uint32_t begin, uint32_t end)
{
    for (uint32_t i = begin; i != end; i++)
    {
        uint32_t y = i & 0xFFFF;
        if (y == 0)
            continue;
        uint32_t x = i & 0xFFFF0000;
        uint32_t q2 = x/y;
        if (q2 > 0xFFFF) // overflowed
            continue;
        
        uint16_t q1 = divHi16(x >> 16, y);
        if (q1 != q2)
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(print_mutex);
            std::cout << x << '/' << y << ": " << q1 << " != " << q2 << '\n';
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t[MAX_THREAD];
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; i++)
        t[i] = std::thread(testdiv, std::numeric_limits<T>::max()/MAX_THREAD*i);
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; i++)
        t[i].join();
    
    std::thread t2[MAX_THREAD];
    constexpr uint32_t length = std::numeric_limits<uint32_t>::max()/MAX_THREAD;
    uint32_t begin, end = length;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD - 1; i++)
    {
        begin = end;
        end  += length;
        t2[i] = std::thread(testdiv16, begin, end);
    }
    t2[MAX_THREAD - 1] = std::thread(testdiv, end, UINT32_MAX);
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_THREAD; i++)
        t2[i].join();
    std::cout << "Done\n";
}
```